# Golang: struct embedding vs "aliasing"

Tags: go, types

I know about struct embedding

```golang
type newType struct {someStruct}
```

I know about type aliasing:

```golang
type newType = someStruct
```

But is there any practical reason to use

```golang
type newType someStruct
```

What about primitive types?

```golang
type newType int
```

What is the right name for such a definition?

Comment: It's a type definition, it doesn't have any other name as far as I know. It allows you to easily define a type that has the same structure, or memory layout as the one you're referencing in the definition.

Answer (score 7):

Naming: All of the snippets are *[type declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)*.  One of the declarations is a *[type alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations)* (the one with the =).  The remaining declarations are *[type definitions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions)*. The first of those definitions uses a struct with an embedded field.

The code `type newType someStruct` is useful when one wants to define a new type with the same memory layout as some other struct type.  This might because the programmer wants to use different methods on the same memory layout.

The code `type newType int` is useful for defining a type with a semantic difference from `int` or for attaching methods to the primitive type.  See [reflect.Kind](https://godoc.org/reflect#Kind) for one example.

Comment: Two main reasons for the last case: 1) to define a *semantic* difference between two memory-equivalent types (e.g. `rune` vs `int32`), or 2) to define different method sets on two memory-equivalent types; though 1 without 2 is not uncommon, 2 without 1 is.

Answer (score 1):

> struct embedding vs “aliasing”

---

You are conflating to different constructs.

For the definition of struct embedding, see [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

---

Here's an explanation of and the rationale for Go type aliases.

> [Go 1.9 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9) (released 2017/08/24)
>
> [Changes to the language](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#language)
>
> Go now supports type aliases to support gradual code repair while
>   moving a type between packages. The [type alias design document](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/18130-type-alias.md)
>   and [an article on refactoring](https://talks.golang.org/2016/refactor.article) cover the problem in detail. In
>   short, a type alias declaration has the form:
>
> ```
> type T1 = T2
> ```
>
> This declaration introduces an alias name `T1`—an alternate
>   spelling—for the type denoted by `T2`; that is, both `T1` and `T2`
>   denote the same type.

---